# Ruby - slice all characters till underscore in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string like this `solution_10` and I would like to remove the part `solution_` from it, the number after the underscore will increase, it can be `100`, `1000` and even larger. I cant seem to wrap my head around on how to do this.

I have tried to use `slice!(0, 9)` but that gives me `solution_`, I then tried `slice!(0, -2)` but that gives me null,

I then tried using `solution_10[1..9]` this gives me `ortable_1`

So my question is how to get rid of all characters till `underscore`, all I want is the number after the underscore.

Comment: You might be able to get away with `"solution_10"[/\d+\z/]`.

Comment: if you want to use `slice`, then `'solution_10'.slice(/\d+\z/)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"solution_10"[/(?<=_).*/]
#⇒ "10"
```

or simply just get digits until the end of the line:

```
"solution_10"[/\d+\z/]
#⇒ "10"
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`String#split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) method

```
'solution_10'.split('_').last #will return original string if no underscore present
#=> "10"

'solution_10'.split('_')[1] #will return nil if no underscore present
#=> "10"
```

Comment: Note that `split('_').last` will return the string itself if it doesn't contain an underscore. You could use `split('_')[1]` instead to make it return `nil` in that case.

Answer (score 5):

> I cant seem to wrap my head around on how to do this.

First of all, [`slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-slice) and its shortcut [`[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) can be used in many ways. One way is by providing a *start* index and a *length*:

```
'hello'[2, 3] #=> "llo" # 3 characters, starting at index 2
#  ^^^
```

You can use that variant if you know the length in advance. But since the number part in your string could be `10` or `100` or `1000`, you don't.

Another way is to provide a range, denoting the *start* and *end* index:

```
'hello'[2..3] #=> "ll"  # substring from index 2 to index 3
#  ^^
```

In this variant, Ruby will determine the length for you. You can also provide negative indices to count from the end. `-1` is the last character, `-2` the second to last and so on.

> So my question is how to get rid of all characters till underscore, all I want is the number after the underscore.

We have to get the [`index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-index) of the underscore:

```
s = "solution_10"
i = s.index('_') #=> 8
```

Now we can get the substring from that index to the last character via:

```
s[i..-1] #=> "_10"
```

Apparently, we're off by one, so let's add 1:

```
s[i+1..-1] #=> "10"
```

There you go.

---

Note that this approach will not necessarily return a number (or numeric string), it will simply return everything after the first underscore:

```
s = 'foo_bar'
i = s.index('_') #=> 3
s[i+1..-1]       #=> "bar"
```

It will also fail miserably if the string does not contain an underscore, because `i` would be `nil`:

```
s = 'foo'
i = s.index('_') #=> nil
s[i+1..-1]       #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

For a more robust solution, you can pass a regular expression to `slice` / `[]` as already shown in the other answers. Here's a version that matches an underscored followed by a number at the end of the string. The number part is captured and returned:

```
"solution_10"[/_(\d+)\z/, 1] #=> "10"
#              _          literal underscore
#               (   )     capture group (the `1` argument refers to this)
#                \d+      one or more digits
#                    \z   end of string
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking out the time and writing such a detailed explanation :) this helped a lot.

Comment: Current Rubocop likes to slice with nothing at the end of the range to mean til the end instead of -1 i.e s[i+1..]

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
'solution_10'[/\d+/]
#=> "10"
```

Comment: The parentheses are superfluous. If they are supposed to be a capture group, you have to move them inside the regular expression. But that isn't needed either.

Comment: With the fix @Stefan suggested this must be the simplest solution. It also has the advantage that it works with `"my_solution_10"`.  `'solution_10'.gsub(/\D/,'') #=> "10"` is the flip side.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just make use of regex

```
"solution_10".scan(/\d+/).last
#=> "10"
```